# Como verificar que una fecha es valida?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime

Estoy intentando crear una función que verifique que una fecha es válida de acuerdo a los días del mes y si el año es bisiesto o no, pero no he logrado encontrar la solución.

Es decir, una fecha como: 31, 06, 2000 no es válida, ya que junio solo tiene 30 días, en cambio, 25, 06, 2000 si es una fecha válida.

Intenté hacerlo de la manera abajo, creando un nuevo objeto Date, y verificando que los métodos para obtener el día, mes y año devuelven los mismos valores que se le pasó como argumento a la función, pero no funciona, devuelve true cuando la fecha es inválida y viceversa:

```
  isDateValid (year, month, day) {
    const date = new Date(year, month, day);


    if (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == month && date.getDate() == day) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
```

PD: tambien tome en cuenta que el numero devuelto por date.getMonth el mes Enero corresponde al mes 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu código funciona de maravilla, está bien hecho y te da el resultado correcto... y entonces?, el problema está en la construcción de la fecha, en la clase **Date**, el constructor que usas, toma como parámetros, el año, el mes y el día, pero hay un pequeño detalle, los meses van del "**0**" al "**11**", osea, cuando tu le estás pasando la fecha **31-06-2000**, que crees que debería fallar, le estás pasando **31-Mayo-2000** que es una fecha válida, puedes probar la falla pasándo como argumento por ejemplo **2000-12-31** que si bien parece ser "31 de Diciembre de 2000" es una fecha no válida, aunque a partir de ella, la clase **Date** crea una fecha válida, agregando "el sobrante" a la fecha, osea te creará la fecha "31 de Enero de 2001"

```js
let date;

function isDateValid( year, month, day ) {
    date = new Date( year, month, day );
    if( date.getFullYear() == year && 
        date.getMonth() == month && 
        date.getDate() == day ) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

   // creamos erroneamente la fecha 31 de Diciembre
let fecha = new Date( 2000, 12, 31 );
   // al imprimir, nos encontramos con el 31 de Enero
console.log( fecha );

   // 29 de Febrero
console.log( isDateValid( 2022, 01, 29 ));
console.log( date );

   // 28 de Febrero
console.log( isDateValid( 2022, 01, 28 ));
console.log( date );
```

Comment: Hola, efectivamente el error estaba en que él para el usuario, la función para obtener el mes, devuelve el mes como un entero en base que el index es 0, por lo tanto, enero es el mes 0.
Lo resolví sustrayendo 1 del input del usuario al momento de hacer las verificaciones.

Answer (score 3):

Se puede validar que el objeto Date creado sea válido usando `isFinite` o `isNan`

```js
let d = new Date("foo");
console.log("isFinite foo " + isFinite(d))

let d2 = new Date("1/1/2023");
console.log("isFinite 1/1/2023 " + isFinite(d2))
console.log("!isNaN 1/1/2023 " + !isNaN(d2))

let d3 = new Date("2023-06-31T00:01:02");
console.log("isFinite 2023-06-31 " + isFinite(d3))
console.log("!isNaN 2023-06-31 " + !isNaN(d3))
```